# Blob trigger re-running copy on publish

Tags: c#, azure-blob-storage, azure-blob-trigger

I've got a fairly simple blob trigger in C# which just copies over files from one container to another when a file is uploaded. The frustrating thing is that any time I publish the trigger from Visual Studio it reruns over all the files and recopies them (this then potentially runs up 100s of logic app instances to process the new files). Is there any way to stop the trigger re-running over old files, maybe an attribute or filter that I've missed? Otherwise I could resort to a last-modified filter in my code, but better if it is built in. Many thanks.

Comment: This behavior is strange. [This article](https://learn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-trigger?tabs=csharp) talks about blob receipts and states "no blob trigger function gets called more than once for the same new or updated blob".

Comment: I follow this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-storage-blob-triggered-function) to create an Azure Blob storage triggered function, and it will be triggered when files are uploaded or updated. The old files do not trigger it. Please share more details about your operations.